# C++ Console not taking keyboard input

Tags: c++, keyboard

*Resolved*

I'm using Microsoft Visual Stuido 2017 and built a basic console utility program. When using the debug mode(F5) everything works flawlessly. Then I chose to batch build and see if I could run the .exe. The .exe runs my welcoming message and even greets me with a flashing cursor but won't accept any kind of keyboard input. I try hitting random letters on my keyboard and none pop up; oddly though alt + F4 works so my keyboard likely isn't the issue. I am honestly one hundred percent clueless as to what it might be. It should be noted my save location differs in a few ways. Could it be an issue with my system and not the program?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5aWF.png)

*I have iostream and other appropriate C++ standard libraries included through my header files*

```
int main() {
    cout << "Welcome to FTC console commands" << endl 
        << endl << "Please enter a command or 'HELP' for help" << endl 
        << "You can exit at anytime by typing 'EXIT'" << endl; //Welcome

    while (true) { //main loop

        league1 = load();

        string Input; //Input
        cin >> Input;

        system("CLS");

        if (Input == "EXIT") break; //Checking where to go depending on Input
        else if (Input == "ADD_MATCH") addMatch(league1);
        else if (Input == "ADD_TEAM") addTeam(league1);
        else if (Input == "HELP") help();
        else if (Input == "RANK") rankings(league1);
        else if (Input == "SAVE") save(league1);
        else cout << "Invalid Input... try again or see 'HELP'" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could put a breakpoint on the IDE and see what's going wrong. However, You could also do `cout<<Input<<endl;` after the `cin>>` statement. While debugging also please comment out the `system("CLS")`. It's likely that this is the clear screen you're seeing.

Comment: I added a picture, sorry should've done that at the start. When I hit keys they aren't showing up in the console. It's much like I'm not hitting keys in the first place.

Comment: What is `load()`?  You do see that this mystery function is called before `cin`, and who knows what this function does.

Comment: Are you sure `load()` isn't taking time to run? Can you move the `String ...; cin>>` lines before `load()` and check if you can then enter the data into `Input`?

Comment: That's the issue! I need to get a rubber duck... Thanks for the help! Basically its trying to load from a file that isn't in the right spot. 'load()' is a function I defined for my file manager. Its either getting caught on the lack of  a file or its creating one that doesn't have the footer to tell it when to stop.

Comment: Please do not put "Resolved" in the title. Instead, post an answer to your own question and accept it. The system recognizes this as meaning that the problem is resolved, so that it can be used to answer other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load();` was referencing a file that didn't exist, so even if it made its own, it lacked the footer I defined and it wouldn't stop reading the document. Simply created the document it was trying to load and added the footer.